# Can site be used as a factor in a multiple regression model?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, interaction

I am studying two sites with different fertility and soil texture. In the model I used the data from both sites. I would like to know if could I could use the site as a factor (variable) in the model? For this way I can assess interactions. If yes, can I fit my model this way?

```
model1 <- lm(litterproduction ~ site*(richness + basalarea + density + deciduous), 
             data=dataX)
```

Comment: Are your data / observations are nested within several sites? Is your response variable, `litterproduction`, a count variable?

Comment: I have two experiments with the same design, but each one is located in differents places. Litterproduction is a variable quantitative (kilograms per hectare).

Comment: @Deivid, kilograms per hectare cannot be <0, but if your values aren't very close to 0 you can probably treat them as normal. Be sure to check a QQ-plot of your residuals.

Comment: Gung, thank you. Yes, I checked the residuals (homogeneity of variance and normality). I have one more question: I would like to use the stepwise to select the best model. Could I use the same model to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that your data / observations are nested within several `sites`, and that you expect the effect of your variables differs between these sites.  (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

The typical way to deal with this type of situation is to include `site` as a random effect in a mixed effects model.  You could then get random slopes for each variable for each site.  You don't *have* to do it this way, however.  If you prefer, you can enter `site` into your model as a fixed effect, which seems to be your preference.  Thus, your approach is fine.

In making this decision, you should be aware that the models answer slightly different questions, though.  Using random effects will estimate the mean effect of your variables in the population of sites from which your sites were sampled.  Using a fixed effects strategy will let you estimate the effect of your variables in those specific sites only.

Comment: Yes, I have effects in my answers variables between these sites, for that I would like to insert in my model the site with a factor.

Comment: @Deivid, you can use `site` as a factor as I discuss above.